# Apply where condition on same column twice or thrice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a catalog page on which products are getting displayed via ajax.
The code for Ajax call is below:

```
function updateProducts(opts){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "func.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(records){
        $('#slider').html(makeProdiv(records));

      }
    });
  }
```

and func.php has code as below:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=filter', 'root', '');

  $select = 'SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc';
  $from = ' FROM product';
  $where = ' WHERE TRUE';

  $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

  if (in_array("Shoes", $opts)) { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Shoes'"; }
  if (in_array("Belt", $opts))  { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Belt'"; }
  if (in_array("lt1th", $opts)) { $where .= " AND prate < 1000"; }
  if (in_array("mr1th", $opts)) { $where .= " AND prate > 1000"; }
  if (in_array("lth", $opts))   { $where .= " order by prate asc"; }
  if (in_array("htl", $opts))   { $where .= " order by prate desc"; }

  $sql = $select . $from . $where;
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
```

The problem i am facing are:

1. When i select both Belt and Shoes in the filter then no result is getting displayed because the query turns out as below on selecting both options:

`SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc FROM product WHERE TRUE AND ptype = 'Shoes' AND ptype = 'Belt'`

Please let me know how to achieve that as single product check is working fine.

Comment: Is there any other reason to check `WHERE TRUE`? If not, that is not needed here. You could directly append your `WHERE` clause for `Shoes` and `Belts`

Comment: Nothing specific for 'WHERE TRUE`

Comment: You mean want both results of `Shoes` and `belts`. right?

Comment: Try using the IN clause, i.e. 'AND ptype in ("'.implode('"', $opts).'")' . Remember to escape user inputs.

Comment: @DavidLin, in `$opts` i have another values also. Shoes and belt are one of them. It includes `color` also. So your approach will fail in that case

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for all your responses

i figured it out and achieved as below:

```
$allptype = array('Belt','Shoes');
$selectedptype = array();
  foreach($allptype as $ptype){
    if(in_array($ptype,$opts)){
        $selectedptype[] = $ptype;
    }
  }
  if(count($selectedptype)){
    $where .= " AND ptype IN ('".implode("', '", $selectedptype)."')";
  }
```

It seems gud to me. If sombody has another approach , feel free to post.

Comment: Yes. You got the best way man. And one more thing, `foreach(` iteration not needed one. `$opts` already an array. You can directly pass `$opts` into `implode`. like `$where .= " AND ptype IN ('".implode("', '", $opts)."')";`

Comment: No Ranjith.. i can not use `$opts` directly as `$opts` has product type, product color, product rate etc and if do that way then query will fail.. correct me if i am wrong here

Comment: @ranjith .. do u know any other approach to display products and filter both via ajax ..

Answer (score 0):

if (in_array("Shoes", $opts)) { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Shoes'"; }
  if (in_array("Belt", $opts))  { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Belt'"; }

Why you didn't use 'or' instead?
So the full sql will be like

"SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc FROM product WHERE TRUE AND ptype = 'Shoes' AND ptype = 'Belt'"
Is that what you want?

Comment: yes i want that when i check both then results should be displayed for Belt and shoes and query is getting generated at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `TRUE` from `WHERE` clause.

Your `ptype` value is won't same at all time(mean if it is `shoes` or `belts`)

So you query need to change like this,

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=filter', 'root', '');

  $select = 'SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc';
  $from   = ' FROM product';
  $where  = ' WHERE';

  $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

  if (in_array("Shoes", $opts) && in_array("Belt", $opts)) { 
     $where .= " ptype = 'Shoes' OR ptype = 'Belt'"; 
  }
  else if (in_array("Shoes", $opts)) { 
     $where .= " ptype = 'Shoes'"; 
  }
  else if (in_array("Belt", $opts))  { 
     $where .= " ptype = 'Belt'"; 
  }

  $sql = $select . $from . $where;
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
```

Comment: it is fyn @Ranjith.. See the query is getting generated at Run time. Please let me know how to incorporate this in run time.

Comment: again not good approach.. see if i have 3 colors in `$opts` and i have to apply filter then i have to make combinations for all 3 colors having all 3 at one time, having 2 at one time and then having 1 at one time.. this will result into long code.. can't b there any alternative approach

Comment: @Gags : You mean `$opts` will have 2 or more possibilities, right?

Comment: Yes Ranjith.. it can have any values.. u got it right

Comment: @Gags : See your array contains a string like `shoes` , `Belt` , etc.. Then you check the string is presence in array, you added `WHERE` clause like `$where .= " ptype = 'Shoes'"` , `$where .= " ptype = 'Belt'"`.. etc., Okies. This `ptype = 'Shoes'` you added manually, not came from database. I think there is no other way to achieve these. You need check manual only.